# $\mathbb{R^2} \backslash (0,0)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

Here is my proof of this -

Suppose $X = \mathbb{R^2} \backslash (0,0)$ is not connected.

$\implies$ There exists non-empty disjoint open subsets $U, V \subseteq \mathbb{R^2} \backslash (0,0)$ s.t. $U \cup V = X$.

$\implies \overline {U \cup V} = \overline X = X$

But $U, V$ open $\implies U \cup V \neq \overline {U \cup V}$

I.e. $U \cup V \neq X$. This is a contradiction, hence $X = \mathbb{R^2} \backslash (0,0)$ is connected.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: $U,V$ open does not imply $U\cup V\ne \overline{U\cup V}$.  For example, suppose that one of $U$ or $V$ is the entire space.  Or consider $U=(-\infty, 1), V=(0, \infty)$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Where do you make use of anything specific of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Show that the space is ven more: path-connected. Of the circle having two given points as diameter endpoints at most one point can be missing, hence at least one arc is left intact.

Comment: Is it not trivially path connected and hence connected?

Comment: Sorry, I understand that we need to formally give a path, I suppose I was just looking for an easy way out!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the fact that $X$ is connected iff
$
f:X\to \{0,1\} 
$ is continuous $\implies f$ is constant.

details:

Find a continuous path $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$ from $x$ to $y$:
$$
\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y
$$ (look at Hagen von Eitzen's post for an explicit construction).

$f\circ\gamma:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ is continuous, hence is constant: $f(x)=
f\circ\gamma(0) = f\circ\gamma(1)=f(y)$.

---

The equivalence with your definition:

- if $X=A\cup B$ with $A,B$ non empty open sets, then 
  define $f(x) = 1_A(x)$. Then $f^{-1}(1), f^{-1}(0)$ are open, hence $f$ is continuous, and $f$ is not constant.
- If $f:X\to \{0,1\}$  is continuous: the choice $A=f^{-1}(1), B=f^{-1}(0)$ proves that $X$ is not connected.

---

NB: you can prove that for an *open space* there is equivalence between 
being connected and path connected.

NB2: the result remains true for $X-\{x_1,\dots x_n\}$ instead of $X-\{x\}$.

Comment: What is the line $Ox$, I haven't seen that notation before?

Comment: this is the line $L$ such as $(0,0)\in L, x\in L$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what is happening now. It seems we have to 'split' $\gamma$ into three sub paths and move along each of them in turn to get from $x$ to $y$. What kind of notation can be used for that?

Comment: I made the proof of the equivalence between both definitions.

Comment: Roughly it seems like we have that $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(i_1) = \frac{x}{|x|}, \gamma(i_2) = \frac{y}{|y|}, \gamma(1) = y$ where $0 < i_1 < i_2 < 1$ which gives a path from $x$ to $y$ via the unit circle. I don't know how to define $\gamma$ such that this is the case though. Would it be acceptable just to define $\gamma$ as having these values at these locations and provide an explanation that the path is travelling via the unit circle?

Comment: yes. Defining $\gamma$ more procisely is a waste of time.